# Sublime Text 3 auto-Indentation with comments

Tags: sublimetext3, indentation, auto-indent

I have been using ST3 to write python for a while, but the auto-indentation has confused me sometimes.

I am currently writing a python function and I noticed that if there is a comment at the end of a line of code, the auto-indentation by pressing enter at middle of the line won't work. For example, I have the following lines:

`fig = plt.figure(num = 0, figsize = (10,10))`

`fig = plt.figure(num = 0, figsize = (10,10)) #This creates a figure`

By pressing 'Enter' before 'figsize' in both lines, the first line would auto-indent while the second wouldn't:
[Indent Issue Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ExAdq.png)

Does anyone has any solution to this? I can add the comment after using the indentation but it is always a fuss to do this.

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question and describe in a little more detail what "doesn't work" means? Some examples (preferably text) would be helpful, too.

Comment: @MattDMo Just updated with an image of the problem! Thanks!

Comment: Well, I can reproduce the issue on the latest dev release of ST4, so it's not just you. I'd suggest looking through the issues at the [Sublime Text issue tracker](https://github.com/sublimehq/sublime_text/issues) and filing a new one if you can't find a duplicate.